# Change matrix name for shard in Firebase Test Lab

Tags: firebase, testing, continuous-integration, automated-tests, firebase-test-lab

In this week I started using Firebase Test Lab and it's awesome, but I have a problem. Can I change the name of the matrix? In documentation I don't see any solutions.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3jkk.png

Comment: I'm curious why you feel the need to change the name of a matrix? 

Please note that all matrix names need to be globally unique, so letting users set the name could cause issues (e.g. user accidentally reuses a name, or two different users pick the same name).

Comment: I don't feel the need to change it, but the client insisted. But I already explained that it is impossible :) I needed support

Comment: As we are running test from CI/CD tool Codemagic for us it's important to identify when test run corresponds to a specific app build. @P.Davis

Comment: Does Codemagic call the Cloud Testing API directly, or is it invoking a provided client such as `gcloud` or `flank`?

If the former, you can set the `clientInfoDetails` field in the create matrix request sent to the Testing API with any key:value information you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported in Firebase Test Lab. You cannot change this name/identifier.